# Return an array from a function in PowerShell 3.0

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to have PowerShell 3.0 return an array from a function. Unfortunately this is not very well documented as I have spent the past two days scouring Google for examples on this. I am this close to rewriting the entire script in C# and calling it a day.

The script checks a set of URLS which are contained in a variable. The function in question gets the list of URL's from an array and loops through the array adding the HTTP status code to a new array. The function does all of the above, however it does not return the array. Here is the function in question:

```
function URLCheck ($URLStatusCode)
{
    foreach($uri in $URLStatusCode )
    {
        $result = @()
        $time = try
        {
            $request = $null
            ## Check response time of requested URI.
            $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri}
            $result1.TotalMilliseconds
        }
        catch
        {
            <# If request generates exception such as 401, 404 302 etc,
            pull status code and add to array that will be emailed to users #>
            $request = $_.exception.response
            $time = -1
        }
        $result += [PSCustomObject] @{
            Time = Get-Date;
            Uri = $uri;
            StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode; 
            StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription; 
            ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength; 
            TimeTaken =  $time;
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

I call the like this:

```
URLCheck $LinuxNonProdURLList
$result
```

I also printed the contents of $result after the execution and I notice that it is empty. However if I were to put the return statement in the foreach loop, it does send the information to the console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more troubleshooting I figured out that the array $result was only local to the function. I declared the array outside of the foreach loop and that fixed the error. Here is the updated code:

```
function URLCheck ($URLStatusCode)
{
    $result = @()
    foreach($uri in $URLStatusCode )
    {
        $time = try
        {
            $request = $null
            ## Check response time of requested URI.
            $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri}
            $result1.TotalMilliseconds
        }
        catch
        {
            <# If request generates exception such as 401, 404 302 etc,
            pull status code and add to array that will be emailed to users #>
            $request = $_.exception.response
            $time = -1
        }
        $result += [PSCustomObject] @{
            Time = Get-Date;
            Uri = $uri;
            StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode; 
            StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription; 
            ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength; 
            TimeTaken =  $time;
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

Comment: Just a quick PowerShell note.  You can lose the $result+= and the return statement and the function will work the same.